# How to enable Jscript intellisense (VS2010) in class library project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have a normal class library project that will provide some custom web controls for usage in other (normal ASP.NET Web form) projects.

Those controls will have java script files and I want to use Intellisense in there - especially for the MS Ajax library.

My class library project references `System.Web.Extensions`, and I added a new JScript file to a Resources\Scripts folder in my project and set it to embedded resource (to be able to reference it from my control and deliver it). So in this script I tried this in the very first line:

```
 /// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.js" />
```

But no JScript Intellisense is available (i.e. the `Sys` and `Type` global objects are not available in Intellisense).

I also tried this:

```
/// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

but this has the same (negative) results. I also discovered the same behavior when adding a JScript file to a normal web project - also here is no Intellisense available.

So the question is: *How can I activate intellisense for the MS Ajax library in my script files?*

Additionally: From the web projects (that will only reference my compiled cotnrol assembly, NOT the assembly project with its source), how can I add Intellisense support for the files defined there? The reference with name and assembly seems not to work too.

Comment: I suppose you never got this to work?

Comment: I have a dirty workaround: ReSharper allows JS intellisense for all .js Files in a solution. So I copied the JS files and added them to a dummy project in my solution. and intellisense works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a path and not just a filename unless the file actually lives in the same folder. also, many files have separate code and vsdoc, try to look for a -vsdoc.js file and reference that.

Comment: As said, I want to reference a script in an *assembly*, because there is not Microsoft.Ajax file to reference.